# Adding a np array to my np array is messing up my expected shape

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do a opencourseware in ML and I have this snippet of tsv file as data

[image]

I am trying to create a bag of words for car_name, I have gone through the data file, created a np array for car_name based on what the name was and added each data entry as a row with the following code

```
def lab3():
    data = DataWithCarNamesAsBagOfWords()
    
    
    
def DataWithCarNamesAsBagOfWords():    
    wordsBag, lines = createBagOfWord()
    data = []
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip().split("\t")
        # print(f"l[-1] : {l[-1]}")
        carNameFeature = np.zeros((1, len(wordsBag)))
        carNames = l[-1].split(" ")
        for name in carNames:
            for i in range(len(wordsBag)):
                if name == wordsBag[i]:
                    carNameFeature[0][i] = 1
                    break
        
        l[-1] = carNameFeature
        # print(f"l after update : {l}")
        row = []
        for item in l:
            if isinstance(item, np.ndarray):
                row.append(item)
            else:
                row.append(float(item))
        data.append(row)
        
    return np.array(data, dtype=object)





def createBagOfWord():
    with open("auto-mpg.tsv", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    wordsBag = []
    for line in lines[1:]:
        l = line.strip().split('\t')
        carName  = l[-1].split(" ")
        for word in carName:
            if word.lower() not in wordsBag:
                wordsBag.append(word.lower())

    return (wordsBag, lines[1:]) 
        
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lab3()
```

in lab3() I want to slice data into separate labels and data the labels is the column mpg so I wanted to slice data as

```
data[0:len(data), 0]
```

to get all the columns but I am getting an error in doing so, upon inspection I am getting the shape of data as (393,). I am not getting the number of columns in the shape and I can't seem to understand why is this so. If there are no columns I won't be able to slice the array

Comment: Casting your list of numpy arrays into a numpy array with object dtype will simply create a 1-D numpy array of numpy arrays. It doesn't infer the number of columns since you could've had different sized numpy arrays in the original list.

Comment: It's difficult to test your code without the .tsv file, but I would recommend instantiating your `data` as a 2D numpy array from the outset with `data = np.zeros((num_lines, num_columns), dtype = object)`. Then in the loop, use something like `data[i] = row` instead of append.

Comment: `data[:, 0]` selects the first column, returning a 1d array.

Comment: @MichaelCao, generally list append performs about as well as row assignment.

Comment: @hpaulj The issue is that his resulting numpy array is considered 1D; there is no second index to slice. My approach to make the second index transparent is to explicitly set the shape at the outset with a numpy array rather than build up from an empty list. That's why I recommended assignment rather than append.

Comment: Without the `tsv` file we can't recreate your run (not that we'd want to).  Within `lab3` is might help to see the result of `wordsBag, lines`.  And later the `data` list - before array creation.  Oh, and a full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

On examining the data file, I found out that the tsv file had one empty row, which was causing all sort of problems for the desired shape of my arrays